# JSON datas showing only once

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to fetch data from a JSON file. But it shows only once. when i close application and open again, it doesn't show the results. When i'm clear the application's caches, it shows my results again. There is no error in logcat and app is not crushing either. I don't know what to do. Is there a common solution for this problem or is that something i did?

This is my Games.class;

```
    public class Games extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<ModelGames> modelGames;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_games);

        modelGames = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.gamesPageRecyclerView);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        jsonParse();

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager gamesLiLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gamesLiLayoutManager);

        GamesAdapter adapter = new GamesAdapter(this, modelGames);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void jsonParse() {
        String popularIn2019 = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?dates=2019-01-01,2019-12-31&ordering=-added";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, popularIn2019, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                JSONObject result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String gameName = result.getString("name");
                                String gameImage = result.getString("background_image");
                                modelGames.add(new ModelGames(gameName, gameImage));
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

This is my GamesAdapter;

```
public class GamesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GamesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ModelGames> mList;

    GamesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ModelGames> list){
        mContext = context;
        mList = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_game_items, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ModelGames getItem = mList.get(position);
        TextView gameName = holder.game_title;
        ImageView gameImage = holder.game_image;
        Glide.with(mContext).asBitmap().load(getItem.getImage()).into(gameImage);

        gameName.setText(mList.get(position).getText());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView game_image;
        TextView game_title;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            game_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardviewImage);
            game_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardviewText);


        }
    }
}
```

and this is my ModelGames;

```
public class ModelGames {

    private String text, image;

    public ModelGames(String text, String image) {
        this.text = text;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Share your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: I ran your network code, it is working perfectly fine. I'm getting a response even after restarting the app. How are you determining that you're not getting a response? Try putting log inside onResponse method of volley and print the response.

Comment: @ParagPawar My network code, recyclerview and adapter are working well. But when i put them together, it's working just once

Comment: Okay I'll implement the recyclerview, can you update your post and add adapter code, you've added model class as your adapter

Comment: @ParagPawar oh, right. I fixed now

Comment: @MuhammetFatihGül Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Found the issue, after adding your JSON data to arraylist of ModelGames, you're not calling

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So, first of all, make your adapter as a global variable before onCreate:

```
private GamesAdapter adapter;
```

and then inside your onCreate do this:

```
 adapter = new GamesAdapter(this, modelGames);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Inside you jsonParse() method (inside onResponse) do something like following:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String gameName = result.getString("name");
    String gameImage = result.getString("background_image");
    modelGames.add(new ModelGames(gameName, gameImage));
}

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Basically, when you do the network call, it happens asynchronously (on network thread).
So, even if you have added data to your list, your adapter is unaware of it, so notifying it is very important.

I hope this helps, comment down if it doesn't solve your problem.